# Trying to install Netbeans 7.4

Tags: command-line, sh

When trying to install netbeans-7.4-linux.sh, I cannot open my personal folder where the file is located. I try cd /home/myusername/downloads, but I get: File or folder does not exist. If I try to copy the file to a different folder outside my personal folders, I get a Permission denied type of error.
Using Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: what's your personal folder name?

Comment: are you copying your files as user or as root? those are not the same even if you set up your user with administrator privileges.

Comment: how do I copy my files as root?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us i) exactly what you're trying to do. What are the file names and which directories are they in? ii) show us the _exact_ command you tried and the errors you got iii) what .sh are you talking about?

Comment: "cd /home/myusername/downloads" needs to be "cd /home/$USER/downloads" ($USER will be changed into your username). the literal "myusername" would only work if you have a user named exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (xterm is fine) and execute  `cd ~`  to browse your home directory; after that execute `pwd` to print the directory's name.
Execute `sudo chown YOURUSERNAME FILE` to change the file owner of a file and be able to edit it; use `chmod +x FILE` to make a binary file executable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Lorenzo. When I try to do cd /juan, I get No file or folder found answer- This is the problem, I cannot open my personal folder or copy anything to folders below my personal ones.

Comment: Please note that Linux is case sensitive;check if your home exists by browsing the directory three from the top before doing anything. If you (or some software) deleted the home folder, use 'sudo mkdir' to create a new home folder and 'sudo chown yourUserName:yourUserName pathOfNewDir' to own it. To set the new folder as your home execute 'sudo usermod -d homeDirPath yourUserName'. Logout & login to make the changes effective.

Comment: I tried capitals and it didn't work, also I didn't delete the folder.

Comment: Use ' find / -type d -name "directory" ' if you want, to do a full search. If you really can't find the home then follow the procedure I've written; don't worry it's safe. :)

Comment: the home folder it's there, the issue is that I cannot access it through terminal for installing netbeans.

Comment: Execute 'sudo mount -a', 'sudo chown -Rv yourusername yourdirectory' and 'chmod -R -f +rwx yourdirectory'; this will make sure that the home is writable by your user. Be sure to access the folder as root ('sudo su') or with the user that created it.